# Setting whether an R session is `interactive`

Tags: r, rpy2

Is `interactive()` in #rstats based on some settable option?

I'm getting download-timers (and other cruft) printed to an Rmarkdown pdf constructed using a snakemake/rpy2 pipeline. Admittedly, I could use `Rscript` instead of `rpy2` to run my R code, but using rpy2 seems a lot neater.

Ideally, I'd like to use `rpy2` to link to an R-session and just indicate that `R` is running non-interactively. But I can't work out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

rpy2 allows the user to toggle the interactive flag at any time (it will start with the interactive flag on by default). This is otherwise not possible from R. R runs either in batch mode, non-interactive, or in interactive mode (e.g., the R console).

The doc is incomplete unfortunately, and the feature is only mentioned in a changelog:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/changes.html#release-2-1-0

(look for `set_interactive`).

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't actually work out how to use it. Interactive-use only seems to be mentioned in the `rpy2.rinterface` docs, and `set_interactive` is present in `rinterface/_rinterface.c`. So I tried `from rpy2 import rinterface as ri` ; but `rinterface` only exports `set_[choosefile|cleanup|flushconsole|initoptions|readconsole|resetconsole|showfiles|showmessage|writeconsole_regular|writeconsole_warnerror]`.

Comment: May be not imported into `rpy2.rinterface`. Try in `rpy2.rinterface._rinterface`.